# c# script class in unity cannot be found despite no compile errors and names matching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to amend a c# sharp script to an empty object but I am constantly given the "script class cannot be found" error, not allowing me to add the script to the object. every fix I have found for this issue includes either there being a compile error which is found in the console (my console is entirely empty) or that the names do not match (which they 100% do).
Here is my code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Levels to load")]
    public string _newGameLevel;
    private string levelToLoad;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject noSavedGameDialogue = null;

    public void newgameYes()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(_newGameLevel);
    }
    public void loadgameYes()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Savedlevel"))
    {
        levelToLoad = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SavedLevel");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
    }
    else
    {
      noSavedGameDialogue.SetActive(true);
    }
}
    public void QuitButton()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Please edit the question to include a [mre]. For unity questions this includes enough information to reproduce the problem starting from a new project. There is likely something else happening not mentioned here which is producing the error observed. Some possible avenues for investigation without starting from scratch include 1. Forcing a recompile with ctrl+r to cause previously cleared compiler errors to reappear. 2. Deleting irrelevant assets, scenes, gameobjects, components, etc until the problem disappears. See [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: Can you double check that script is in your unity project folder through the file manager? If you added the script in Unity I have never had problems with file locations being saved in the wrong file location...

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason: the name of the script is different from the class.

Sometimes unity can (in my experience) fail finding the script if the only difference is lower/upper case. When that happens I think I usually need to delete and add a new script.

Try adding a script with different name.

Also try edit->preferences->externaltools-> regenerate project files

Answer (score 0):

Rename the script in editor, then rename it back, unity will recognize it again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Unity 2022.2.2f1.

When I was trying to add new script to one of my InventorySlot which was a prefab, I saw the same error.
So I added the new script by pressing 'Add Component' button under the 'Inspector' window of InventorySlot. Doing this the new scipt was generated under the 'Assets' folder.

[image: New script default location]

The Inspector window of the InventorySlot looks like this.

[image: When the new scipt added under 'Assets' folder]

After that I could move the script to another folder, for example Assets/Scripts/UI/Tooltip without any error message.

[image: Move the new script to another folder]

I don't know why this happens but I could solve the problem.